# Django keep HTML formatting with passed string

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, escaping

I am very new to Django and I've encountered the following problem. I have a small script to give me a random quote from my list

```
@register.simple_tag(name='quote')
def random_quote():
    quote, author = random.choice(quotes_list)
    return """%s <br> %s""" %(quote, author)
```

And I call the selected quote in my template as:

```
{% load quotes %}{% quote %}
```

which is working just fine, however I'm not able to pass the HTML formatting together with my quote. How can I escape HTML in my quote to get e.g. a single line break between quote and author? Thank you!

Comment: Read more about `safe` templatetag

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping

Comment: Thanks, `{% autoescape off %}{% quote %}{% endautoescape %}` solved my problem!